# Jssor Slider - How to add checkbox to thumb image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jssor

How to add a checkbox to each thumb image

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 20px; width: 410px; height: 450px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div>   
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />           
        <img u="image" src="../img/travel/01.jpg" />
        <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-01.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>              
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" />           
        <img u="image" src="../img/travel/02.jpg" />
        <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-02.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

It is not working. It doesn't show the checkbox in UI.

Can any help me with this.

Comment: Can you post the code in a working http://jsfiddle.net. I imagine there is some CSS/JS controlling the slides which is messing up the layout.

Comment: Hi, Can you please check this slider [http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html) i'm using this slider. Please download the code from this site.

Comment: @Nagarjuna DIlip: Are you expecting something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/R8DPN/

Comment: Hi, No..checkbox is not displayed at all.   Please check my code [http://jsfiddle.net/R8DPN/2/] (http://jsfiddle.net/R8DPN/2/). Left hand side there a image. Check box should appear along with the image.

Comment: How to share screen short of my output?

Comment: Hi, Image are not getting loaded & unable to select the checkbox. Please download the sample code from this link http://www.jssor.com/download.html. Choose /image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the sample, http://www.jssor.com/testcase/thumbnail-with-checkbox.source.html

Please note the following manner to select your checkbox.

```
        var thumbnailNavigatorContainer = $(".jssort07");
        var checkbox01 = thumbnailNavigatorContainer.find(".chk01");
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm out of station. Thanks for your solution. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Please always add style position, top, left, width, height for static element.

Try following code,

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 20px; width: 410px; height: 450px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div>           
        <img u="image" src="../img/travel/01.jpg" />
        <div u="thumb" style="background-image: url(../img/travel/thumb-01.jpg);" >
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px; />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>              
        <img u="image" src="../img/travel/02.jpg" />
        <div u="thumb" style="background-image: url(../img/travel/thumb-02.jpg);" >
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px; />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Btw, you can can use any html code for your thumbnail.

---

I checked the code and detected it by using the 'inspect element' tool of browser, your check box was covered by other ui.
The reason is that the prototype of thumbnail in 'Thumbnail Navigator Skin 02' is as follows,

```
            <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 99px; height: 66px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <div class=w><thumbnailtemplate style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></thumbnailtemplate></div>
                <div class=c>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I checked and tested with following thumbnail navigator skins, it works OK.

skin\thumbnail-07.source.html

skin\thumbnail-08.source.html

skin\thumbnail-11.source.html

skin\thumbnail-12.source.html

Comment: Hi, Image is not getting loaded & unable to select the checkbox. Please download the sample code from this link [http://www.jssor.com/download.html](http://www.jssor.com/download.html). Choose /image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html

Comment: Hi,  Still the same... Unable to select the Check box & image is not loading... I think you are giving solution for bigger image which is selected. I want it for left side slider all thumb nail images should appear checkboxs...It will be helpful if you provide solution for the slider thumbnail images..I want to share the screen short of my UI to u for better understanding... but, i don't know how to share...  Thanks for you patience & response.

Comment: Hi, Sorry ignore my above message... Yes as you said.. That skin 02 is covering. How to over come of it...? & thumb image is not displayed... I commented skin 02 it is working fine.. but thumnail images are not displaying... Thumbnail images are showing blank (black colour)....

Comment: I added another answer.